# The argument type 'ShapePainter' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CustomPainter?'. error in painter of flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-custompainter

i got this error with using painet in flutter:

> The argument type 'ShapePainter' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CustomPainter?'.

and my code is:

```
class ClipWidget extends StatelessWidget {


final Widget? childWidget;

  const ClipWidget({Key? key, this.childWidget}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [CustomPaint(
        size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,200.0),
        painter: ShapePainter(),
      ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class ShapePainter extends CustomPaint {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  Paint paint0 = Paint()
  ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
  ..strokeWidth = 1;
  paint0.shader = ui.Gradient.linear(Offset(size.width*0.00,size.height*0.48),Offset(size.width,size.height*0.48),[Color(0xe16ae353),Color(0xffffffff)],[0.00,1.00]);

  Path path0 = Path();
  path0.moveTo(size.width*0.0016500,size.height*0.0141000);
  path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.0010313,size.height*0.6965250,size.width*0.0008250,size.height*0.9240000);
  path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.1690625,size.height*0.7614000,size.width*0.2513500,size.height*0.4848000);
  path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.4153875,size.height*0.7299000,size.width*0.5283625,size.height*0.7412000);
  path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.6602125,size.height*0.7236500,size.width*0.7950000,size.height*0.2750000);
  path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.8485000,size.height*0.7852000,size.width*0.9422375,size.height*0.9509000);
  path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.9981250,size.height*0.9071500,size.width*0.9991500,size.height*0.7100000);
  path0.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.0150000);
  canvas.drawPath(path0, paint0);


  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

how can i fix this error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShapePainter`   will  extend `CustomPainter`  instead of `CustomPaint`

```dart
class ShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
```